# C# AutoResetEvent does not reset

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have spent two whole days figuring out why the threading in my WinForms application doesn't work. I really need some help here.

In my application, button1_Click event will call a method but if the method runs for too long, I want to abort it.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false; 
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ExtractData));
    t1.Start();

    //Wait for 5 seconds, if t1 is not finished executing, abort the thread
    autoResetEvent.WaitOne(5000);
    if (autoResetEvent.WaitOne()== false)
    {
        t1.Abort();
    }
    button1.Enabled = true; 
}

private void ExtractData()
{
    //Get data from web service..

    autoResetEvent.Set();
}
```

I consider button1_Click event as my main thread and ExtractData() will be in thread t1. After ExtractData() is finished doing it's work, I want autoResetEvent.Set() to wake up autoResetEvent.WaitOne() in the main thread & therefore the main thread execution can be finished. However the main thread will just stop at autoResetEvent.WaitOne() & remains in waiting state. Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: read about [TPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) - your code will be much easier to read

Comment: Bad ideas: Have the UI thread waiting. Abort a thread. Good ideas: Use async/await. Use BeginInvoke. Use CancellationToken.

Comment: As an aside, you can use `Thread.Join` and pass in a timeout rather than use a `AutoResetEvent`

Comment: Also, calling `Thread.Abort` is a bad idea. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.abort?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: An AutoResetEvent automatically becomes unsignalled once anything has successfully waited on it (hence the "Auto" part of its name). So after `autoResetEvent.WaitOne(5000);` returns `true` it will block in the following call. You probably want a ManualResetEvent. In any case, you should rethink this approach because calling `Thread.Abort()` is pretty much always a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable inputs. I've only learned about threading two days ago. I will get this working then explore other option like async/await

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're waiting on the event twice, and after the first time the event has been reset, as it is an auto reset event. Change this:

```
autoResetEvent.WaitOne(5000);
if (autoResetEvent.WaitOne()== false)
{
    t1.Abort();
}
```

to

```
if (autoResetEvent.WaitOne(5000)== false)
{
    t1.Abort();
}
```

So that you only wait on it once.

Also, as others have mentioned, your code is blocking the gui thread for the entire 5 seconds that you wait, meaning your applcation will become unresponsive. You should look into other options, such as using `async`/`await`.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I'm finally able to get my code working and I improved it by using async/await.